# Efficient way of horizontal concatenation without tiling

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have two (large) arrays. For illustration purposes I'm using a simple example below:

```
In [14]: arr1 = np.arange(32*512).reshape(32, 512)
In [15]: arr2 = np.arange(512).reshape(1, 512)
```

And I wanted to do a horizontal concatenation of these arrays (i.e. concatenation along axis 1). I came up with the following approach to achieve this:

```
In [16]: np.hstack([arr1, np.tile(arr2, (arr1.shape[0], 1))]).shape
Out[16]: (32, 1024)
```

This works as intended. However, I would like to know whether there are any other efficient ways of doing this concatenation without using `numpy.tile`. I'm afraid I would blow-up my memory requirements since the arrays are really huge.

If it's possible avoid this duplication of rows (to match the dimensions of `arr1`), maybe using broadcasting, then it'd be great!

---

**P.S.** The reason why I want to avoid this copying is because of linear growth of memory requirements:

```
In [20]: arr2.nbytes
Out[20]: 4096

In [19]: np.tile(arr2, (arr1.shape[0], 1)).nbytes
Out[19]: 131072

In [22]: arr1.shape[0] * arr2.nbytes
Out[22]: 131072
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preallocate and use broadcasting but it won't save much (I'd expect peak memory usage to go down by roughly a quarter):

```
arr1 = np.arange(32*512).reshape(32, 512)
arr2 = np.arange(512).reshape(1, 512)
out = np.empty((32, 1024), arr1.dtype)
out[:, :512] = arr1
out[:, 512:] = arr2
out
#array([[    0,     1,     2, ...,   509,   510,   511],
#       [  512,   513,   514, ...,   509,   510,   511],
#       [ 1024,  1025,  1026, ...,   509,   510,   511],
#       ...,
#       [14848, 14849, 14850, ...,   509,   510,   511],
#       [15360, 15361, 15362, ...,   509,   510,   511],
#       [15872, 15873, 15874, ...,   509,   510,   511]])
```

Comment: Nice! I just checked and the end memory requirement for both approaches are same but this approach might be far more faster than mine since we avoid explicit copy..